# Do I have to use dynamic SQL in order to add a section to the where clause since we need SQLParameter-s

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My app in constructing a query that is to used later. DBCommand and SQLParameter-s are used for security reasons and escaping. I would like to add a section (coming as a textbox input) on the beginning of the where clause so in the end the section would look like:

```
WHERE @SECTION1 AND COLUMN1 = @PARAMETER1 AND COLUMN2 = @PARAMETER2 AND ...
```

When I run the app, it fails with the exception:
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.
Of course, it had all been working before I added @SECTION1 .

I have found on forums that I have to use dynamic SQL in order to do this, but I obviously can't since we need SQLParameters for security purposes. Is there any other way to achieve this?
Thank you for answering

Comment: If the params are defined inside sql then you have to use EXEC inside sql to run it

Comment: What does @SECTION1 look like?

Comment: Gordon, the section is whatever the admin user enters in the textbox. Our admins know structure of some database tables which they are supposed to use and set the beginning of the where clause. Of course, I must assure myself they will not drop a table or do something similar with adding the section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/ to see how you use dynamic sql.

But if you run code and execute sql i suggest to build th sql statements e.g. in your c# application.

Comment: So, sp_exectesql is the answer. Thanks

Comment: YvesR, do you have some link to help me on the approach you are suggesting to use for building t-sql statement from c#? Our app has multiple layers, I am not sure if I will be able to utilize sp_exectesql from where I need it. Thanks

Comment: Google has more you can read in your life time :) Example: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet All you want then is to build your statements and call it from ADO.NET